# Function not returning variable in dart

Tags: dart

I made a function in dart that is meant to change a variable and return it for use later in the program. It doesn't change the variable like it is supposed to. Here is my code:

```
String example = "not working :/";

String make(){
  String example = "Hello World";
  return example;
  
}

void main() {
  make();
  print(example);
}
```

I want it to print out hello world but instead I still get the original "not working :/"

I tried everything I could to make the function change the variable with no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `make()` you are declaring a local named `example` with the declaration `String example = "Hello World"`. This re-declared `example` [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `example`.

There are a couple things you could do.

#### 1. Assign the global

```dart
String example = "not working :/";

void make() {
  example = "Hello World";
}

void main() {
  make();
  print(example);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Note the assignment of `example`, without a declaration. `example = ...` is an assignment; `String example = ...` is a declaration.

This is an example of a function with a global [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

#### 2. Return a value

```dart
String example = "not working :/";

String make() {
  return "Hello World";
}

void main() {
  example = make();
  print(example);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Generally speaking, approach #2 should be preferred due to the lack of side effect, unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise.

It's possible there are some use cases in which it would make sense to combine approaches #1 and #2 (i.e. *both* assign a global as well as return the value, as it appears you're attempting to do in your example code). But I suggest limiting yourself to one or the other unless there's a specific reason to do otherwise.